# Vim: Using custom highlight groups in statusline

Tags: vim, statusline

When customising my vim statusline, I'm able to use the following syntax to make use of the highlight group `User1`:

```
set statusline+=%1*
```

Let's say I have some custom highlights like:

```
highlight StatusLineStyle ctermbg=34 ctermfg=15 guibg=#00af00 guifg=#ffffff
```

How can I make use of those custom syntax colourings in my `statusline`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's explained in `:help 'statusline'`, just above the part on `%1*`:

```
# - Set highlight group. The name must follow and then a # again.
    Thus use %#HLname# for highlight group HLname. The same
    highlighting is used, also for the statusline of non-current
    windows.
```

So…

```
set statusline+=%#StatusLineStyle#%f#
```

Answer (score 3):

Similar to the `%N*`, there's `%#HLname#` for custom highlight group names. Actually, it's documented right above that (at `:help 'statusline'`). So, for your example, use

```
:set statusline+=%#StatusLineStyle#
```

Alternatively, you could use the `User1..9` styles, and *link* your highlight group to it:

```
:highlight link User1 StatusLineStyle
```